# How High For A Condensate Standpipe?

Tags: vent, drain-waste-vent, sewer

I have a new Navien NPE-240A2 condensing tankless water heater that I'm installing in an existing small water heater cabinet accessible from the exterior of my house. The current tankless is an older non-condensing type and there is no condensate drain presently. The utility closet is right next to a bathroom so I planned to add a new 1.5” standpipe in the crawlspace and extend it up into the utility closet. It will have a p-trap and be plumbed into the existing drain within 5 feet of a vent stack shared by the other fixtures in the bathroom.

My question is, is there a code requirement for how high the standpipe must be? Since the closet is small I would prefer it be low in the closet but wasn't sure if there was a requirement to be a certain height similar to a washing machine standpipe (which by the way is clear on the other side of the house, too far to run the condensate drain to.)

Comment: If the closet is adjacent to the bathroom vanity, another way is to run the condensate through the basin's drain by replacing the tailpiece with a dishwasher one.  This provides an air gap and a trap with no new plumbing.

Answer (score 0):

The condensate drain can not have a “stand pipe” it won’t drain if plumbed into a drain I suggest above a p -trap as this prevents some blockages by mold

Comment: The standpipe I am thinking of would be just like a standard washing machine standpipe - so it would have a p-trap and the 1/2" flexible condensate drain tubing would have an air gap and would be dripping directly into the standpipe and the included p-trap. Would that fit the bill?

Comment: That would be fine josh with low flow devices you don’t need a tall stand pipe like washing machines have. But an air gap prior to a P trap is just the ticket